# Drawing a tick mark in the progressbar if the process is done

Tags: html, css

I was created a simple progressbar with CSS & HTML. Here I used three classes active, inactive & done.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: "";
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
  background-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.active+li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
  background-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.inactive:before {
  border-color: #7d7d7d;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li.inactive+li:after {
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="done"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="inactive"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

If the class is active it will show the circle with `background-color: green`,
If the class is inactive it will show the circle with `background-color: grey` 
What i want is while using class '`done`' i need to show the circle with `background-color: green` and tick mark inside the green circle like this. [image]
I tried a lot but not able to finish it. Please someone help me. [Here is my working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4yu5qpbw/)

Answer (score 5):

Use tick mark in `content: "✓";`

```css
.container {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 100px auto; 
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: "";
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }
  .progressbar li.done:before {
      content: "✓";
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
  }
  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      content: none;
  }
  .progressbar li.active {
      color: green;
  }
  .progressbar li.active:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.active + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.done:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.done + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.inactive:before {
      border-color: #7d7d7d;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li.inactive + li:after {
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
      <li class="done"></li>
      <li class="active"></li>
      <li class="inactive"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As per your Requirements using css

```css
.container {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 100px auto; 
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: "";
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }
  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      content: none;
  }
  .progressbar li.active {
      color: green;
  }
  .progressbar li.active:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.active + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.done:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.done + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.inactive:before {
      border-color: #7d7d7d;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li.inactive + li:after {
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  
  .progressbar li.done {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .progressbar li.done:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0.3em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4.2em;
    top: 26%;
    margin-top: -0.2em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index:9;
    background-color: #55b776;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="done"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="inactive"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the working fiddle link. jsfiddle.net/awayF/491. The problem is i don't know how to merge with my code.

Comment: Lets add `done` class to one more element it remvoes the horizontal line. Then it won't working fine.

Comment: @htoniv because using after we are generating tick mark for done and for other line, so we can't generate line. For that case you need to content: "✓";.

Comment: What do we have to do to make this vertical?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the `content` to the tick mark when the `done` class is applied.

```
.progressbar li.done:before {
    content: "✔";
}
```

Wirking fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ordmpf59/

Comment: this tick mark doesn't looks nice. Please see the sample tickmark inside the circle.