# Progress bar with checkpoints - custom shape

Tags: html, css, angular, progress-bar, angular-animations

I am making a custom progress bar(you could say a timeline) with checkpoints. Checkpoints are in the shape of a circle. There are 3 parts to this - 1. Circles, 2. Colored progress bar and 3. black progress bar.
I have stacked them with z-indices. Circles above colored bar which is above the black bar.

When I click on somewhere on the progress bar the colored bar expands it width to that point - did the animation on angular. But I couldn't find a way to fill up the circle when the colored bar reaches it. Is it possible to give the circle the color of the progress bar behind it?

The circle should fill up from left to right. Please suggest any method. I will give stackblitz link -
[Stackblitz - demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-progress-bar).

[image: This is the custom progress bar]

Comment: I somehow got it to work. But the circle are filled with background color. I wasn't able to find a way top fill it from left to right when the blue bar reaches its left end. The updated stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-progress-bar-jxscaw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing a tick mark in the progressbar if the process is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512276/drawing-a-tick-mark-in-the-progressbar-if-the-process-is-done)

Comment: No, it doesn't @Tumi